# Git - Get all commits made by an author on the current branch after multiple merges from other branches

Tags: git

I have '**branch-1**' made out of a branch called '**develop'**, and I have made multiple commits on it. Now I have another branch named **'release'**, which does not have all of develop's commits. So, I can't directly create a Pull Request to release from branch-1.

I have created another branch '**branch-2**' out of release. Now, I want all my commits from branch-1 to be **cherry picked** or somehow moved to branch-2. For me, getting all commit hashes is enough.

I tried using

```
git log --author=Author --no-merges --first-parent branch-1
```

but this command only retrieves all the commits that I made after the last merge to branch-1. Is there any way I could get the commits I made on one branch-1 excluding commits of mine that are brought to branch-1 from merges.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your tree layout. Can you show the results of `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` and say which commits you want moved onto `branch-2`?

Comment: @Andrew it's not about the layout. i just want the hashes of all commits that I made on the branch 'branch-1', so that i can cherry pick all of them to 'branch-2'